# International phone numbers validation

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation

I've tried many regex, but I'm still not able to find the one for accepting these kind of phone numbers:

```
003466655544
 and
+34666555444
 and 
(+34)666555444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regular expression I'm using for validating those phone numbers. Hope it helps...

```
['validate-phoneStrict', 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (+34)123-456-7890 or 00346297647171.', function(v) {
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/.test(v);
```